# Interpret Queries of Lucene

Tags: java, sql, lucene, full-text-search, search-engine

I was wondering if there is any way to interpret Queries of Lucene in simple terms?

For example :

Example # 1:

Input Query - name:John

Output - Interpreted as : Find all entries where attribute "name" is equal "John".

Example # 2:

Input Query - name:John AND phoneNumber:1234

Output - Interpreted as : Find all entries where attribute "name" is equal to "John" and attribute "phoneNumber" is equal to "1234".

Any tutorials in this regard will be helpful,

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Lucene documentation](http://lucene.apache.org/core/2_9_4/queryparsersyntax.html) does a pretty decent job in explaining basic queries and their interpretation. It seems as though that's all you're looking for; once you get into some of the more advanced query types, it gets hairy, but the documentation should always be your first stop; it's fairly comprehensive.

**Edit:** Ah, you want *automated* query explanation. I don't know of any that currently exist; I think you'll have to write your own, but if you're starting with standard `QueryParser` Syntax, I think the best input for your interpreter would be the output of `QueryParser.parse()`. That breaks down the free text into Lucene query objects that shouldn't be too difficult to wrap in a utility function that outputs a plain-English string for each one.

Comment: Actually I am aware of the Lucene queries but instead what I am trying to do is create a Lucene Query Interpreter where a user can insert the query, suppose : "name:John" and I can get output something like : "Interpreted as : Find all entries where attribute "name" is equal "John"."

Comment: Check the edit. Shouldn't be too bad, especially if you're reasonably familiar with the query types already.

Comment: Yes Exactly, Let me give a try and get back to you. Thanks

Comment: Ended up creating my own query parser in extension with Lucene's parser :)

Comment: Glad you were able to work out a solution; thanks for following up!